# Why is my Netlify-hosted Gatsby site 301 redirecting to a path without a domain?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, gatsby, netlify

I did a quick check to see make sure my site was 301 redirecting from:

`https://inlunar.com/news/iceye-shows-off-new-sharp-images-from-satellite`

to the www. version:

`https://www.inlunar.com/news/iceye-shows-off-new-sharp-images-from-satellite`

However, when I checked, I found that there was an extra 301 redirect happening from the www. url to:

`/news/iceye-shows-off-new-sharp-images-from-satellite`

without the domain name anywhere to be found. Here is the full log of that second redirect:

```
>>> https://www.inlunar.com/news/iceye-shows-off-new-sharp-images-from-satellite

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Cache-Control:  public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:   Wed, 17 Jun 2020 01:09:17 GMT
Etag:   "8af6153ff17d129285674adb734ca0e3-ssl"
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=31536000
Age:    0
Server: Netlify
X-NF-Request-ID:    69351fad-bde6-4674-a9b8-fe017a45ee0c-2118676
Location:   /news/iceye-shows-off-new-sharp-images-from-satellite/
```

Why is this second 301 redirect happening?

Answer (score 0):

Netlify appears to be redirecting to the location of the current request with a trailing slash, consistent with [their documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#trailing-slash), in an effort to improve cache hit rates.

As for the omission of the domain, it's simply [a relative URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location#Relative_URL_example).

> Relative URLs are URLs that do not include a scheme or a host. In
>   order to be understood they must be combined with the URL of the
>   original request.
>
> Client request for http://www.example.com/blog:
>
> ```
> GET /blog HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> ```
>
> Server response:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Location: /articles/
> ```
>
> The URL of the location is expanded by the client to
>   http://www.example.com/articles/.